# Ubuntu 16.04 when downloading from youtube, the "recent" folder option is not appearing in the panel of the download window in Firefox 77

Tags: 16.04, firefox, downloads, youtube

Just did a fresh install from usb of Ubuntu 16.04.

My issue is the panel in the download window for Firefox 77 does not show the "recent" location or folder option when downloading from youtube.

How come the "recent" folder option is no longer automatically appearing as part of the typical list of folders in the panel of the download window when the media file FROM YOUTUBE is selected for download?? And can we put it back?

I did research and saw a solution to someone else's problem that does work for me. The answer is to press ALT R. That does work in my case. It shows all recently used locations or folders. This is however temporary since it does not permanently show the "recent" option in the window. It is something that has to be done every time you want to download from youtube.

A thought just struck me that maybe it could be an issue with the extension / plug in??  A new bug?

Thanks in advance for any advice.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj2UQ.png)

Comment: It's odd, but I don't even have a "recent" folder, and also don't remember seeing it in Firefox related windows. Perhaps you can clarify why you think it should appear, where is it, etc.